# Chaining array and string methods in javascript

Tags: javascript, methods, fluent, chaining

I try to chain some array and string methods but it doesn't work. It'd be great if anyone could explain to me why a function such as this doesn't work:

```
const scream = text => text.split('').push('!').join('').toUpperCase()
```

Comment: Check out the docs on `push` (it does not return the array you pushed to, which should be clear if you look at the error that gets thrown)

Comment: push() "returns the new length of the array" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: what is sample text and what is expected

Comment: This looks a complicated version of `(text + '!').toUpperCase()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to return an array with another value instead of [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), which returns the new length, but is not part of a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) for a later joining (which needs an array).

```js
const scream = text => text.split('').concat('!').join('').toUpperCase();

console.log(scream('hi'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Push doesn't return the array. Here's an example that demonstrates what's happening with push, and shows another way to do it:

```js
const scream = text => text.split('').push('!').join('').toUpperCase()

const test = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const result = test.push('!')

console.log(result)

const newScream = text => [
  ...text,
  '!'
].join('').toUpperCase()

newScream('hello')

console.log(newScream('hello'))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add 1 `!` at the end:

```
const scream = text => text.split('').concat('!').join('').toUpperCase();
```

If you want to add it after each letter:

```
const scream = text => text.split('').map(e => e + '!').join('').toUpperCase();
```

The `push` don't return array, so `join` is not called on array in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add character/string at the end of string use `concat(<ch>)` function. If you want to change case to `upper` then use `toUpperCase()` function.

Or

Simply you can use `+` operator to concat two strings and append **!**  to it.

```js
var str = "Hello World";
    var res = str.toUpperCase().concat("!");
    var result = (str + '!').toUpperCase();
    console.log(res);
    console.log(result);
```